# Disable WSDL Generation for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, wsdl, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-webservice

we want to disable the WSDL generation of sharepoint webservices. e.g.

`http://baseaddress/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl`

To enable this we have done the following:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\web.config` added entry

`<system.web> <webServices> <protocols> <remove name="Documentation /> </protocols> </webservices> </system.web>`

Adding the above entry, stops users from accessing this url: `http://baseaddress/_vti_bin/lists.asmx` but if  a user append `?wsdl` at the end of url, the `WSDL still get generated`.

Then we have updated the following entry in the same web.config file:

`<location path="wswsdl.aspx"> <system.web> <authorization> <deny users="*"/> </authorization> </system.web> </location>`

i have also changed all the endpoints with `httpGetEnabled="false"` from `httpGetEnabled="true"` but still no effect

however the wsdl is still getting generated, is there anything further we can do to disable wsdl generation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/b9042670-3fb8-4b89-9c17-76cb265b2844/how-to-hide-wsdl-for-sharepoint-in-webconfig?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy), you can remove/disable web service protocols.

As a test, try in your `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\web.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <remove name="HttpGet"/>
                <remove name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

From [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d881abe1-3ce7-4cc8-be69-1c448b880c4d/iisreset-on-one-specific-web-application?forum=sharepointadminlegacy), you would need at least an `iireset` to apply those changes.

If removing those protocols is too much, you can instead remove an handler:

```xml
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
</handlers>
```

---

If the `?wsdl` is still accessible, you might consider implementing a custom HTTP module to intercept the incoming request and block it if it contains the '?wsdl' query string.

- Open Visual Studio and create a new Class Library project targeting the .NET Framework version that your SharePoint installation uses.
- Add a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.
- Add a new class to the project called `DisableWSDLModule` and replace its contents with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace DisableWSDL
{
    public class DisableWSDLModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
        }

        private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;

            if (context.Request.Url.Query.Contains("?wsdl"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                context.Response.StatusDescription = "Forbidden";
                context.Response.Write("WSDL generation is disabled.");
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Try and:

- Build the project and obtain the resulting DLL file from the bin folder.
- Deploy the DLL to the SharePoint server by copying it to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\{your-web-application-port}\bin` folder. If the '`bin`' folder does not exist, create it.
- Modify the `web.config` file in the SharePoint web application folder (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\{your-web-application-port}\web.config`) to register the custom HTTP module.
  Add the following entry inside the `<system.webServer><modules>` section

  ```xml
  <add name="DisableWSDLModule" type="DisableWSDL.DisableWSDLModule, [Your DLL name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[Your PublicKeyToken]" />
  ```

Replace `[Your DLL name]` and `[Your PublicKeyToken]` with the appropriate values for your compiled DLL.
You can obtain the `PublicKeyToken` using the `sn.exe` tool or by examining the DLL properties in Windows Explorer.

After an `iireset`, any incoming request containing the '`?wsdl`' query string should be blocked with a 403 Forbidden response.

That would be a workaround, to disable WSDL generation for your SharePoint web services.

---

> The web services I want to disable WSDL for are not for a custom application. They are the ones that come default with SharePoint. These web services are SharePoint web services.

Then try:

1. Create a custom HTTP module as described in above. This module will intercept incoming requests and block them if they contain the '`?wsdl`' query string.
2. Deploy the custom HTTP module's DLL to the SharePoint server's Global Assembly Cache (GAC) by copying it to the `C:\Windows\assembly` folder. This will make the module available to all SharePoint web applications.
3. Modify the `web.config` files of the SharePoint web applications for which you want to disable WSDL generation. You can find these files in the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\{your-web-application-port}` folders.
4. Add the following entry inside the <system.webServer> section of each web.config file:

   ```xml
   <add name="DisableWSDLModule" type="DisableWSDL.DisableWSDLModule, [Your DLL name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[Your PublicKeyToken]" />
   ```

   Replace `[Your DLL name]` and `[Your PublicKeyToken]` with the appropriate values for your compiled DLL. You can obtain the `PublicKeyToken` using the `sn.exe` tool or by examining the DLL properties in Windows Explorer.

Finally, as usual, `iireset`.

Comment: The above settings are already there and i have added another one which is `<remove name="Documentation" />`, and i have been doing `iisreset` but the only change that happens is that the user cannot access the asmx file but ?wsdl is still accessible.

Comment: @Baahubali OK. I have edited the answer to propose a workaround.

Comment: what is your web application? is that sharepoint central administration or a custom web applicatin that has been deplohed in sharepoint?

Comment: @Baahubali the term "web application" refers to a SharePoint web application, not the SharePoint Central Administration or a custom web application deployed in SharePoint. Each web application has its own web.config file, located in the corresponding IIS virtual directory (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\{your-web-application-port}). The suggestion provided above aim to disable WSDL generation for web services in a specific SharePoint web application. If you have multiple web applications, you would need to apply the changes to each web application's `web.config` file individually.

Comment: the web services i want to disable wsdl for are not for a custom application. they are the ones that come default with sharepoint. these web services are sharepoint web services.

Comment: @Baahubali OK, I have updated my answer (last section) accordingly.

Comment: the custom solution implementation has resolved the issue. thank you